# Scss - Apply siblling css to child element

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I try to set display block on child element when parent element have active class uding scss.

CSS what I need from SCSS-

```
.menu-item{
  display:block;
}
.menu-item-body{
  display:none;
}
.menu-item.active .menu-item-body{
  display:block;
}
```

SCSS  What try -

```
.menu-item {
     display:block;

  &-body{
     display:none;
  }

   &.active {
      &-body{
         display:block;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `&.active &-body {...}` works, but you won't have an .active wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu-item {
  display: block;
}
.menu-item-body {
  display: none;
}
.menu-item.active .menu-item-body{
  display: block;
}
```

in SCSS is:

```css
.menu-item {
  display:block;
  &-body {
    display:none;
  }
  &.active &-body {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

Use the [SASS playground](https://www.sassmeister.com/) to instantly see the results.